# cURL GraphQL Query in Java

Tags: java, json, android-studio, curl, graphql

I'm trying to implement an API with a GraphQL query in my android app but having trouble with how to go about converting the cURL to java. I'm relatively new to programming so I've been trying to follow tutorials and questions on here but having no luck for the past few days.

Basically the cURL command sends a GraphQL query and returns a json which I'd like to extract specific data from.

The cURL command is as follows

```
curl -v 'https://api.url/' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'x-api-key: <YOUR_API_KEY>' \
--data-binary '{"query":"{ Search(query: \"searchVariable\") {items{description} } }","variables":"{}","operationName":null}'
```

When I run this in the terminal it returns a json string. I would like to return this in my app and extract data from the json. I think I can do this using a json object but cannot get the data in the first place

Here is one method I tried using another tutorial, it builds successfully but crashes as soon as I attempt to call the method.

```
public static String URLConnection() throws IOException, JSONException {
    URL url = new URL("https://api./api/graphql/");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.addRequestProperty("curl", "'https:/api/graphql/'");
    connection.addRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");
    connection.addRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
    connection.addRequestProperty("x-api-key", "'xxxxxxxxxxx'");
    connection.addRequestProperty("--data-binary", "{\"query\":\"{Search(query:\"Query\"){items{description}}}\",\"variables\":\"{}\",\"operationName\":null}");
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.connect();

    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
    jsonParam.getString("description");

    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    os.write(Integer.parseInt(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8")));
    os.close();
    try {
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

        boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();
        if (hasInput) {
            return scanner.next();
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I have tried various methods I have found online using HttpClient, HttpUrlConnection and ProcessBuilder but nothing has worked. I have no real knowledge of this area of java yet so not sure what I should be attempting, I would just like to add a small feature to my app that requires a simple query.